# Google analytics site search not showing search term results

Tags: html, forms, google-analytics

I have been trying to enable site search for my website in google analytics but I am not sure what I'm doing wrongly. The code below is my search bar, I am using GET method so that my url after a search would be something like this `www.test.com/search_results.php?q=apple`.

The Query parameter I am using is "q". There is not a single result or search term if I go to the search terms page under google analytics.

```
<section class="search-bar">
   <div class="search-container">
      <form action="search_results.php" method="GET">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Enter product name" name="q">
         <button type="submit" value="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
   </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: I have this same issue. Did you ever get to the bottom of it?

Answer (score 0):

If the hit is sent to Analytics and you haven't any filter that may block the hit in the View, the configuration in Google Analytics is correct, so try to wait tomorrow and check report again.